# SonarQube Import Project without Compilation

Tags: configuration, installation, sonarqube

I was wondering whether it's possible to add project to SonarQube without actually compiling the code. So far I have found the following ways to add the project to sonarqube:

- ant/maven
- Eclipse

But I haven't found any way to just import the source code without compilation. Currently I have a lot of C#/XML code I have to review, but no compilation instructions (although the project is using VisualStudio anyway).

1. Is it possible to use sonar client of some kind to just import the source code in a directory to sonar without compilation.
2. Is there a way to integrate sonar client with VisualStudio to make it import the code into sonarqube?

Answer (score 0):

I dont think so. Without compilation dll's are not generated. These Dll's are needed for sonar to do any kind of analysis. So, It is not feasible to achieve what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

May it be for Java or C#, both related SonarQube plugins can analyse code that hasn't been compiled. You must just be aware that some issues won't be detected because the engine requires the byte code / MSIL available to be able to run some advanced rules.

Check out our [sample C# project](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-examples/tree/master/projects/languages/csharp) and its README file to see how to analyse a C# .NET project without building it.

Comment: Hi @Fabrice, This link is not found. Can you please share the latest link.